# Error while Installing DirectAdmin on a Digital Ocean droplet

Tags: digital-ocean, directadmin, controlpanel

I was installing DA on a Digital Ocean droplet then I ran into an error :

```
virtual memory exhausted: Cannot allocate memory
make: *** [ext/fileinfo/libmagic/apprentice.lo] Error 1
Changed secure_php option from no to yes
PHP has been secured.
Job for httpd.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status httpd.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

I have a personal DA license and my DigitalOcean droplet is 1GB Memory/ 25GB Disk and using CentOS 7.6 64bits.

I've been stucking at this error for about 3 hours and still don't know what to do next, please help me out, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it !

Turned out, I need to add more ram or create swap. So I did create swap on my vps and then I reinstalled DA, then everything worked perfectly.

Hope this will help anybody running into the same prolem like me.